# Wrapping all methods of a specific trait

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Say I have a trait:

```
trait Foo {
    def getFoo: Int
    def setFoo(i: Int): Unit
}
```

I would like to wrap all methods of this trait (and others), without actually specifying all the signatures again.

Something like:

```
class LoggingWrapper[T](wrappedInstance: T) extends T {
    // what to do here if I wanted to log every call to methods in T
    // without redefining the signatures?
}
```

Logging is just a simple usecase, others would be adding timeouts, memoizing/caching etc.

How would I do this in Scala 2.11? Runtime reflection? Compiler macro?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025700/can-i-do-aspect-oriented-programming-in-scala